# How can I find string in a given sequneces and copy whole sequence to another textfield?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to find given sequence in textarea and copy it to another field. For example my input and textarea would be like this :

Input:  CGGGAGGAA
Texarea: 
@M04644:45:147451:110237731
AGGGCGATGTCCTGGGATACGCGGGTGTCACGGGAGGAACCTGATCTGCCCAAATCTG
+
11>1AD?DAC333EFFAFGGGGCC9A-9;A--9-AAFB?--99-@A9--/;/B/;: 
@a0add382:1aaaa1:11023:24dsa31
AGGGCGATGTCCTGGGATACGCGGGTGTCATATGCCTTCCTGATCTGCCCAACCATCTG
+
11>1AD?DAC333EFFAFGGGGCC9A-9;A--9-AAFB?--99-@A9--/;/B/;: 
. 
. 
.

and this text keeps going on. Now I want to find all the CGGGAGGAA sequences from the textarea value and push the previous line, the line contains CGGGAGGAA and the next two lines into second textarea. So my second area would be like this :

@a0add382:1aaaa1:11023:24dsa31
AGGGCGATGTCCTGGGATACGCGGGTGTCATATGCCTTCCTGATCTGCCCAACCATCTG
+
11>1AD?DAC333EFFAFGGGGCC9A-9;A--9-AAFB?--99-@A9--/;/B/;:

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```js
document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('click', stringSearch);

function stringSearch() {
    var searchSequence = document.getElementById('searchSequence').value;
    var text = document.getElementById('text').value;
    var result = [];
    
    if(searchSequence.length > 0 && text.includes(searchSequence)) {
        alert("found");
    } else {
        alert("Not found");
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="searchSequence" type="text"> <br>
    <br>
    <textarea id="text" name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" wrap="off">

    </textarea> <br>

    <textarea name="" id="copy" cols="30" rows="10" wrap="off"></textarea> <br>
    
    <button type="button" id="search">Search</button>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the confusing thing is your expected result doesn't match the lines you say you want ...

Comment: How are your sequences seperated ?

Comment: It is not separated. There is no spaces between them and there is no word wrap so every line is a new line.

Comment: @HDkilic - changed the answer a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the input text on end-of-line character

search through each line

if found, push the appropriate values to the array

```js
document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('click', stringSearch);

function stringSearch() {
  const searchSequence = document.getElementById('searchSequence').value;
  const text = document.getElementById('text').value;
  const dest = document.getElementById('copy');
  const lines = text.split(/\r?\n/g);
  const result = lines.flatMap((line, i) => line.includes(searchSequence) ? lines.slice(i-1, i+3) : []);
  
  if (result.length) {
    dest.value = result.join('\n');
  } else {
    dest.value="**not found**";
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="searchSequence" type="text"> <br>
<br>
<textarea id="text" cols="30" rows="10" wrap="off"></textarea>
<br/><br/>
<textarea id="copy" cols="30" rows="10" wrap="off"></textarea>
<br/>
<button type="button" id="search">Search</button>
```